# what is that job that cannot be done without "lsof"?

Tags: lsof

I want to know the use of the overwhelming output of `lsof` and maybe a specific example where `lsof` feels like a blessing.

Comment: There was a user with a rogue database connection last week. We used `lsof -i :[port number]` to see which process it was. Very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I've never used this function but I found the page which describes the topic. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/lsof-command-examples/